# Followed a terrible guide and ran "yum remove pcre*" on my CentOS 5.5. Now it appears the server is down

Tags: centos, yum, pcre

What can I do? Even "yum" is not available.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't run `yum remove pcre *` with a space? Did you get a list of what pcre depends on? I suspect something bigger is going on here. Post logs if you can.

Comment: I am afraid I really just ran yum remove pcre* (without a space).. Ok, now I realize there was exactly a list of dependents. So may be I have just removed hundreds of dependents?

Comment: The log is too long to trace, but the end looks like this: http://img812.imageshack.us/i/sshlog.jpg/

Comment: "yum remove pcre*"... the new "rm -rf /"?

Comment: yup. I guess @hyppy is right. reinstall and restore from back up looks to be your only choice.

Comment: Doesn't `yum` confirm a remove?

Comment: @Nimmy It does ask you (with the default being No), unless you pass the `-y` command line option. Point of interest, newer versions of yum (only tested with yum-3.2.28) will attempt to prevent you from uninstalling yum with a big scary error unless you pass yet another option.

Comment: So the op must of accidentally confirmed it with a keypress?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You really have two options at this point:

1. Attempt to Repair
2. Restore from Backups/Rebuild

Repairing can be a *very* tricky thing to do. You will first need to pull down the rpms for yum and install them manually, assuming rpm will still work. From there look through your yum log and figure out what all packages to reinstall. It could be very labor intensive, and most likely not worth doing.  However, with that disclaimer, this might help you get started. The dependency list for yum consists of:

> python-elementtree python
>   python-iniparse python-sqlite
>   python-urlgrabber rpm rpm-python
>   yum-metadata-parser yum

You may need to get the additional packages for *those* to install, but as I said, this was a starting point. Once you have yum working you need to build out the list of packages that were removed. Since all yum operations are logged, this should actually be fairly easy. By going through `/var/log/yum.log` looking for the string "Erased:" you can determine what was uninstalled. Try running this command to make things easier:

```
cat /var/log/yum.log* | awk '/Erased:/ {print $NF}' > removed_packages.txt
```

Now that you have your package list, you can start building out your re-install list by doing something like:

```
cat removed_packages.txt | xargs -n 100 yum install
```

Although, in the end, a fresh install may be the easiest way to go, particularly if you're in a rush.

Comment: Thanks. You have made it very clear. This is a very expensive lesson. Hope no one makes such mistake again.

Answer (score 3):

> What can I do?

Restore from backups.